# how to set a custom control button's job after adding it to some form?

Tags: c#, winforms, button, user-controls

Im making a userControl named [File_Manager] and i was wondering if i can add a button to this custom control that i can set its job later after adding this custom control to another form .. something like

```
File_Manager fManager = new File_Manager();

fManager.SetFreeButtonJob( MessageBox.Show("Hello") ); // something like this.
```

then whenever user press that button .. the messageBox shows up.

So.. Is it possible to do that?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use the Click event?

Comment: @ionden how do i use Click event from a FORM ..if that button owned by the custom control ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can. Just attach the buttons click handler to the action you pass in.

```
fManager.SetFreeButtonJob(() => MessageBox.Show("Hello"));
private void SetFreeButtonJob(Action action)
{
    button1.Click += (s,e) => action();
}
```

Just note that passing in the Action breaks the encapsulation of user control though. You should probably do something like `SetFreeButtonJob(Jobs.SayHello);` and put the knowledge of what to do inside the control.

Answer (score 0):

Create a [custom event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739.aspx) for your `UserControl` and fire it when your `Button` is clicked. You can then attach an event handler to the custom event in your `Form`. Or you can just raise the `UserControl's` `Click` Event when your `Button` is clicked.

```
public delegate void CustomClickEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e);

public partial class buttonTest : UserControl
{
    public event CustomClickEventHandler CustomClick;
    public buttonTest()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomClick(sender, e);
    }
}
```

and in your `Form`

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    buttonTest1.CustomClick +=new CustomClickEventHandler(userControl1_ButtonClick);

}

private void  userControl1_ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello"); 
}
```

Or as my second option try.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OnClick(e);
}
```

and in your `Form` subscribe to the UserControl's Click event.

```
buttonTest1.Click +=new EventHandler(buttonTest1_Click);


private void buttonTest1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello Again"); 
}
```